# Dagger2 + Mockito: How to Unit Test this scenario?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, dagger-2

I'm working on a team project which has a very coupled code. I'm trying to increase the unit test coverage and I've faced the following scenario:

```
class Foo {
    static void methodA () {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        b.getContent();
    }
}

class Bar {

    @Inject
    DBAcessor mDBAcessor;

    Bar () {
        Dagger2.getInjector().inject(this);
    }

    public Object getContent() {
        mDBAcessor.fetchData();
    }

}
```

I want to unit test `methodA()`, however I don't know if it is possible to do it without passing the `DBAcessor` object via constructor to `Bar()` class. `Bar` should be a POJO model being widely used throughout the project, hence, I don't know if it would be a good idea to change its constructor and impact so many other classes. Any tips on how should I approach this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is wrong design.

Whenever you have an access to the constructor, pass class dependencies into constructor. That really eases unit testing. Class `Bar` should look:

```
class Bar() {

    @Inject DBAcessor mDBAcessor;

    Bar (DBAcessor dbAcessor) {
        this.mDBAcessor = dbAcessor;
    }

    public Object getContent() {
        mDBAcessor.fetchData();
    }
}
```

`Dagger2` methods declared in [`Component`](http://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#building-the-graph) should only be used inside object you don't have an access to the constructor (`Activity` or `Fragment`).

Then nothing prevents you from doing that:

```
DBAccessor dbAccessor = Mockito.mock(DBAccessor.class);
Bar bar = new Bar(dbAccessor);
bar.getContent();
verify(bar, times(1)).fetchData();
```

If you really need to stick to such design, then you can't make unit tests on such object, as `Dagger2` depends on `Application` object, which needs `Context`, which you cannot emulate in unit tests. Write your test as `androidTest`, create appropriate `Activity`, fetch `Bar` object from it and test it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate better in this part? "Dagger2 methods declared in Componentare only to be used inside object you don't have an access to the constructor (Activity or Fragment)."

Comment: Dagger2 has a term 'Component'. Maybe `Application` or `Activity` or custom one. Think of it as scope. If you don't declare `inject` method inside `Component` then you can't use `inject(this)` in code, therefore `Dagger2` won't inject your objects into the class you want (the class you don't have an access to the constructor).

Comment: I understand, I should keep passing the dependencies from the higher level classes to the low level ones. But suppose I start doing that with class `Bar`, where should I call the `inject` on `Foo` class since it has only `static` methods?

Comment: You cannot. It it static. In ideal case static method should accept parameters, return output, not creating any objects, that depend on anything else you can't control when invoking static method. In other case the code is untestable or very weird test cases must be created to test it.

Comment: Okay I got it, thank you very much for all your comments, they have helped me a lot. Just a last question, even in a project where the access to the data layer is constant from different components, I should not be tying up the medium/lower level classes to it, instead I should try to receive its instance from the high level classes?