# How to implement Dependency Injection using Dagger2 on the given scenario? (Manage injection hierarchy on Dagger2)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class Foo {}

class Bar {
    Foo mFoo = new Foo();
}

class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     Bar mBar = new Bar();    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstance) {
        super(savedInstance);
    }    
}
```

From the code above it can be seen that MyActivity depends on Bar and Bar depends on Foo. What is the correct way to implement dependency injection using Dagger2?

---

## My Approach...

So far, the way I've been dealing with this type os scenario was:

**Configuration**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                MainModule.class,
        })
public interface MainComponent {
    void inject(MyActivity myActivity);

    void inject(Bar bar);
}

@Module
class MainModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Foo provideFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Bar provideBar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

**Injection**

```
class Bar {
    @Inject Foo mFoo;

    Bar() {inject(this);}        
}

class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject Bar mBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstance) {
        super(savedInstance);
        inject(this);
    }    
}
```

---

Problem is, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40286820/2068693) answer, it is not supposed to work like that, `Bar` should not call `inject` and have `Foo` passed as parameter. But, what if I need singletons instances of `Foo` in other parts of my project? How should I use Dagger2 to achieve the given scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the signature of the constructor of `Bar` to the following you should achieve the effect that you want (constructor injection).

```
class Bar {
    Foo foo;

    @Inject
    Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }        
}
```

Then you just need to specify the dependency of `Bar` in the provider by writing it as a method parameter like this:

```
@Provides Bar provideBar(Foo foo)
```

Since `Foo` and `Bar` are known to dagger through the `@Provide` methods, dagger will automagically create an instance of `Foo` to obtain an instance of `Bar`. Constructor injection like this will have the added advantage of making your code easy to unit test. In your test, you can swap out a real `Foo` with a mock `Foo` and test the interaction of `Foo` on `Bar`.

Property injection is best only when you don't have access to the constructor (like in Android `Activity` and `Service`). For your other dependencies, it's probably best to use constructor injection.

Comment: And how would be the provide method for `Bar` class on my `Module` class?

Comment: `@Provides Bar provideBar(Foo foo)` (I'll put this in the answer - sorry I forgot!)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a module to provide plain classes. You can annotate the classes directly. To always provide Foo as a singleton, you can annotate the class itself.

```
@Singleton
@Component
public interface MainComponent {
  void inject(MyActivity myActivity);
}

@Singleton
public class Foo {

  @Inject
  public Foo(){}
}

@Singleton
public class Bar {

  private final Foo foo;

  @Inject
  public Bar(final Foo foo){
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

Modules are required when you need to build/configure instances or provide an implementation of an interface. For example:

```
@Module
class MainModule {
  @Singleton
  @Provides
  Gson gson() {
    return new GsonBuilder.create();
  }

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  IBar bar(Bar bar){
    return bar;
  }
}

// You can also provide an interface with the @Binds attribute instead
// of using the traditional @Provides annotation
@Module
abstract class MainBindsModule {
  @Singleton
  @Binds
  abstract IBar bar(Bar bar);
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for the tip!